# How to combine two vectors (I want frequency of values) into a dataframe for a side by side bar plot in R

Tags: r

Can see there are similar questions about actually plotting it but I’m really struggling to get the data organised correctly. I have two vectors storing goals scored from 100,000 simulated football matches for two teams (Home and Away). My end goal is a side by side bar plot showing the frequency for each number of goals.

I’ve used table() to show frequency and then merged them with NA as 0 so that they end up the same length but when I’m trying to use ggplot2 to plot, I’m running into a lot of issues because with how they’re merged I end up with HomeGoals (as in 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), Freq.x and Freq.y (frequencies for Horm/Away) as column headings

Is there a better way to do this? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `position_dodge()` with `ggplot2`
Keep in mind that the data has to be in a *long format* like in the example data.

```
ggplot(df1) + geom_bar( aes(values, fill=ind), position=position_dodge() )
```

[image: barplot]

**Data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(values = c(3L, 7L, 4L, 8L, 10L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 1L, 
8L, 7L, 0L, 8L, 7L, 0L, 10L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 2L, 3L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 
5L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 0L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 9L, 10L, 9L, 2L, 8L, 9L, 
4L, 4L, 3L, 8L, 0L, 5L, 10L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 4L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 
1L, 4L, 5L, 10L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 0L, 9L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 
10L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 10L, 0L, 9L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 
9L, 0L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 9L, 3L, 8L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 6L, 8L, 
3L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 7L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 10L, 4L, 
8L, 6L, 3L, 0L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 10L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 4L, 
9L, 2L, 5L, 9L, 0L, 5L, 9L, 0L, 8L, 6L, 10L, 5L, 0L, 4L, 6L, 
2L, 0L, 2L, 9L, 7L, 9L, 4L, 9L, 9L, 0L, 9L, 2L, 9L, 5L, 0L, 10L, 
0L, 3L, 0L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 0L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 
10L, 6L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 10L, 10L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 8L, 0L, 8L, 6L, 1L, 8L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 
8L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 3L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 10L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 
8L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 
10L, 5L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 10L, 3L, 10L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 
1L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 0L, 9L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 10L, 3L, 5L, 0L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 9L, 0L, 9L, 6L, 
5L, 5L, 8L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 9L, 6L, 10L, 6L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 
10L, 0L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 8L, 5L, 3L, 8L, 4L, 9L, 10L, 
1L, 8L, 4L, 10L, 5L, 10L, 0L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 10L, 8L, 8L, 
7L, 10L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 10L, 10L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 
10L, 1L, 5L, 10L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 9L, 7L, 2L, 9L, 1L, 3L, 10L, 9L, 
3L, 4L, 9L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 10L, 9L, 10L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 8L, 10L, 
10L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 10L, 10L, 5L, 0L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 
5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 5L, 0L, 9L), ind = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), class = "factor", .Label = c("home", 
"away"))), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -400L))
```

Comment: Oh this is exactly what I’m looking for - how would I get two separate vectors into this format?

Comment: Use something like `stack(df)` on a data frame.

Comment: Perfect - and then I can see you just referring to ‘values’ there instead of home/away values separately - is values a variable name here?

Comment: @StephenRussell Inside `aes` you can use the column names of the data.frame put into `ggplot()`. It just happens to be that the stack function creates these names. You can change them to whatever you want and use these within `aes`.

Comment: Oh that’s great, so values refers to both here because both are being shown, and then fill used with position dodge separates them by team?

Comment: @StephenRussell Exactly. `Fill` looks at the categories and counts the unique entries and adds color accordingly. A counterpart would be `col` for color, but it only colorizes the borders.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what kind of issues you are running into. Here's an attempt with simulated data. You may want to consider how you organize your data. I'm assuming you have a data frame (or two vectors).

```
set.seed(1)

df = data.frame(home = sample(0:8, size = 1000, replace = T),
                away = sample(0:6, size = 1000, replace = T))

require(ggplot2)
require(gridExtra)

p1 = ggplot(df) +
    geom_histogram(aes(x = home)) + ggtitle("Home") + xlab("Goals")

p2 = ggplot(df) +
   geom_histogram(aes(x = away)) + ggtitle("Away") + xlab("Goals")

grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol=2)
```

[image]

To get bars side by side:

```
df2 = reshape2::melt(df1, value.name = 'score', variable.names = 'team')

df3 = as.data.frame(table(df2$score, df2$variable))

ggplot(df3, aes(x=Var1, y=Freq, fill=Var2)) + 
    geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah so mine like this, but I want the actual bars side by side rather than the graphs if that makes sense?